# How to combine an IF AND and IF OR function in Excel functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's a little explanation on what I am trying to accomplish...

Whenever column A or column B are filled out, I want column C to say "Card/Key Checked Out".

-BUT-

If and only if both column D and E are filled out, then C to say "Card/Key Returned"... Therefore column C would remain saying "Card/Key Checked Out" if only one of either D or E are filled.

[here is an end-result example file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NYOE.jpg)

So far I have been able to separately come up with the code for each action in:

```
=IF((OR(ISNUMBER(A3), ISTEXT(B3))),"Card/Key Checked Out", "")`
=IF((AND(ISNUMBER(D3), ISTEXT(E3))),"Card Returned","Card/Key Checked Out")
```

...but have not been able to combine the two, thus I keep getting a "too many arguments" error. I do not need help with the data validation or conditional formatting part, just the text changing required in column C when appropriate. If anyone knows how I can combine these two functions or more efficiently be able to accomplish this, please help! Thanks

Comment: Lines 7 and 9 in your example look like they fulfill the same conditions, but have different results. Is this normal? If yes, why?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
=IF((AND(ISNUMBER(D3), ISTEXT(E3))),"Card Returned",IF((OR(ISNUMBER(A3), ISTEXT(B3))),"Card/Key Checked Out", ""))
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much!!

Comment: It's working +1 ☺